# Better way to return validation errors for nested models as json in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have class order, that can content entries. And each entry can be complex type, and consist from another entries.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, allow_destroy: true
end
```

In form i have rails generated fields in form, using fields_for

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="string required form-control" id="order_entries_attributes_1459329286687_members_attributes_1459329286739_title" name="order[entries_attributes][1459329286687][members_attributes][1459329286739][title]" placeholder="Наименование" type="text">
```

So, i submit a form of order, for example with 2 entries, and 5 members with some validation errors ( 2 members without title ) and it passes to controller

```
class OrdersController
  def update
    if @order.update(order_params)
      render json: @order
    else
      render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

And it returns me this

```
{"entries.members.title":["cant be blank"]}
```

Problem is that  i cant find which entry and which member in it, has a validation error, and that's why i cant for example highlight this field. Moreover it merges similar errors. And this is problem.

On submit i pass unique index(in name attributes), and rails correctly use it for creating nested models, it would be nice if error response contained this indexes.

Is there any other way to return nice indexed errors from server, and use rails as api for json without pain?

Comment: its solved in rails 5!

Comment: Do you have a URL for the documentation regarding how Rails 5 solves this?

Comment: cannot find it in docs, but here is simple guide http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/07/errors-can-be-indexed-with-nested-attrbutes-in-rails-5.html

Comment: Thanks @justed_ss! Very much appreciated.

Comment: Found it in the release notes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to have the same format as Rails nested params**

```
render json: {
  order: {
    entries: @order.entries.enum_for(:each_with_index).collect{|entry, index|
      {
        index => {
          id: entry.id,
          errors: entry.errors.to_hash,
          members: entry.members.enum_for(:each_with_index).collect{|member, index|
            { 
              index => {
                id: member.id,
                errors: member.errors.to_hash
              }
            } unless member.valid?
          }.compact
        }
      } unless entry.valid?
    }.compact
  }
}
```

You should get a JSON response like:

```
{
  order: {
    entries: [
      0: {
        id: 1, # nil, if new record
        errors: {},
        members: [
          0: {
            id: 7, # nil, if new record
            errors: {
              title: ["cant be blank"]
            }
          },
          1: {
            id: 13, # nil, if new record
            errors: {
              title: ["cant be blank"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

P.S. Maybe others know a rails-integrated way of doing this. Otherwise, I would say this might be a good feature request for Rails in git.

Comment: Thanks for response
But i dont have ID until success submit, all models (order, entry, member) are new records, and generated using fields_for
Big number in html example is a generated index for submit, like a fields_for creates automaticaly for each nested model

Comment: You're right. Rails auto-assigns random IDs when using `fields_for` on a new resource that has no ID when using `nested_attributes`. I wonder how I could replicate that here.

Comment: My bad, Rails 4 doesn't auto-assigns IDs for new records using fields_for and nested_attributes (I just tested it now). Maybe it used to in Rails 3.2 as I recalled this happening before. I updated my answer to handle no IDs.

Comment: Updated solution solves the problem of updating existing nested models. But if i submit new order with 20 new entries, and 3 of them has validation problem, response will be like "hey, some of your nested records has problem". I need a way to server response would be like: "3,5,8 of new nested models has no title attribute". I wonder why no one faced this problem before.

Comment: I updated my answer to have the same Rails format as when creating a record with nested attributes. Now you can identify 0 index as the first record, 1 as the second record submitted, 2, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks, its still not great and needs some more client side work, but for now its only way to solve problem